# /ɪ/ sometimes sounds like /i/ and sometimes sounds like /e/

Tags: pronunciation

I am confused with the vowel /ɪ/, vowel of IPA, for the American English. Sometimes it sounds like /i/, 'exact', for example, while at other times it sounds like /e/, 'sit', for example.

It indeed sounds differently, but the vowel is the same? Why is this? And how can I determine which sound I should speak?

---

To clarify it, I ask the question in another way.

There is some demonstrations of words which the pronunciations is the same, but sound different between BrE an AmE.

- sit
- pin
- bit

So why is this?

Comment: Are you asking about the sound represented by IPA /ɪ/ or the letter ‹I› (capital 'i') ? The sound /ɪ/ appears in both ‹sit›, pronounced /sɪt/, ‹exact›, ordinarily pronounced /ɪɡˈzækt/), although artificially precise speakers might pronounce ‹exact› with an /ɛ/, thus: /ɛg'zækt/.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, IPA.

Comment: @Goducks it's American accent.

Comment: I am a speaker of AmE, as I believe @GoDucks is, and I agree that ‹sit› is never pronounced /sət/. May I ask what gives you the impression that it is?

Comment: I have met individual speakers of AmE who pronounce certain words that way, e.g. saying *pillow* like "pellow". I'm not aware of any region where this is common though, my impression is that it's an idiosyncratic pronunciation.

Comment: @StoneyB the sound of [Oxford learner's dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sit?q=sit)

Comment: @Zachary - the American English version of "sit" at that link sounds nothing like /sət/ to me.  The British and American versions at that link sound identical to me except that the American speaker has a higher-pitched voice.  Do you hear the difference between "sit" at that page and "set" at [the entry for "set"](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/set_1?isEntryInOtherDict=false) ?

Comment: @Era And even "pellow" employs /ɛ/, not /ə/.

Comment: @GoDucks - Are you sure this is not a case of the [pin/pen merger](http://dialectblog.com/2011/04/17/pin-pen-merger/)?  My wife, from South Louisiana, not only pronounces "pin" and "pen" identically (like /pən/ to my ear), but insists that they *are* identical when other people say them.  I'll ask her what she thinks of sit/set.

Comment: @stangdon don't they actually merge to "pehyun"? Less exaggerated, but a diphthong, sliding from high to low? That's not just a schwa. That's like /peən/. But I don't know anyone that exhibits this merger myself, I could just be wrong.

Comment: I don't understand this question, but it seems OP has either a non-standard understanding of IPA symbols or unusual ideas about how Anglophones normally speak (or both). Whatever - I'm closevoting as Unclear.

Comment: @modulusshift - No, it is distinctly not a dipthong.  I think I know what you're talking about - it's kind of stereotypical Texan accent - but it's not the same thing.  To me (native NYC speaker), the merged pen/pin sounds so precisely like "pen" that it did not even occur to me it could be anything other than "pen" at first.  I wish I could find a good recorded sample, but no joy.

Comment: @stangdon That doesn't sound right to me. The pin-pen merger is generally merging between /ɪ/ and /ɛ/, while /pən/ would sound more like "pun"...

Comment: @Paul - my IPA might be wrong.

Comment: @stangdon Here is a clip that is supposed to be an example of the pin/pen merger: https://www.dropbox.com/s/drebdlqbe545pdc/20150503%20Puzzle%20of%20the%20Day.mp3?dl=0. (What's not hers?)

Comment: @stangdon good to know that's a separate phenomenon. And yeah, the actual IPA is probably /pɛn/.

Comment: @StoneyB If you are an RP speaker, then the American one sounds a lot like /set/. Your /i/, /ɪ/ and /ɛ/ are all more open than our /i/, /ɪ/ and /e/. So your FLEECE can sound like our KIT, and your KIT can sound like our SET! Also I think I'm right in saying that western US has an allophone of KIT  and STRAP before velar consonants, such that KIT sounds very much like FLEECE to someone who doesn't speak that variety and STRAP sounds a lot like FACE :)  I've included some of that in my answer.

Comment: @Araucaria Fersher; but for the first twelve hours this question was up it was asking about an /ɪ/ pronounced as **/ə/**, not either /e/ or /ɛ/.

Comment: @StoneyB Absolutely! As you'll find out if you're ever trying to transcribe a language you've never heard before  - a very fun, educating and worthwhile enterprise - it's extraordinaily hard to pinpoint what you're hearing, and what you're hearing as different from some other sound. I'd put money on the OP hearing something more open and therefore opting for a schwa. It's a good guess at the decription. Especially as KIT is more back than either FLEECE or SET in both RP and Gen Am.

Comment: @StoneyB And actually there's nothing to choose between RP KIT and schwa and a Gen Am KIT. The Gen Am KIT is equidistant between the two! (PS I think /I/ is just a barred capital i in OP's font, but unfortunately not in SE font).

Comment: @Araucaria Certainly contrast is key; but it seems to me that in both GA and RP the obscure full vowel† belongs somewhere in the low back quadrant, and both /ɪ/ and /e/ belong in the high front quadrant. [† I'm always confused when people talk about 'schwa' -- for me that means a reduced unstressed vowel (or an entirely absent vowel).]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KIT vowel, /ɪ/, which we find in the word  *sit*, and the FLEECE vowel, /i/, which we find in *seat* have different pronunciations in Southern Standard British English and General American. In Gen Am they are said with the jaw slightly more open than in British English. So a Gen Am /ɪ/ may sound more /e/-like to someone used to British English.

In the Western United states, the KIT vowel changes when it occurs before velar consonants /k, g/ or /ŋ/. We say that this new sound is an *allophone* of the KIT vowel for these speakers. When people who speak this variety of English have a KIT vowel before a velar consonant it becomes much more like a FLEECE vowel. It is longer and more close.

Because of this when these speakers say, for example the word *sing*, it will sound a lot like the word *seeing* to somebody who does not have the same accent. These speakers also have a different vowel in words like *bag*. Here again we have a velar consonant, /g/. These speakers will use a vowel that sounds like /eɪ/ to other listeners. For people listening, the word  *bag* may seem to rhyme with the word *plague*.

These different possibilities for the vowels which occur in words like *king* and *kin* could be why the Original Poster finds these types of word confusing.

This article [here talks about Western US vowels before velar consonants](http://dialectblog.com/2011/11/10/the-western-us-and-velars/)

Comment: Based on the recent edit by the OP, I think I can understand the OP, but don't know how to explain this. I think in BrE, *sit* and *set* sound not as close to each other as in AmE. (It's quite easy for me to (mis)hear AmE *Git* as *get*.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. *seat*, *sit* and *set* are all further apart and lower in Gen Am than in RP. I think SB might be able to give you a reference. She first told me about this and then I went and researched it. But I can't remember where I went to look ... (I knew about *set* but not *sit* or *seat*)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes, this is exactly what I want to ask.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: I prefer Araucaria's answer, this isn't as relevant to this question after the edits.

Okay, I don't think you know what IPA is. IPA is meant to relate a single phoneme to a single letter. That's why it exists, to give a written form of pronunciation outside of any one language. If two words are pronounced differently, then they are written differently in IPA. /ɪ/ can't sound like /ə/, ever, that's why they're different letters. The letter "I" of the English alphabet can sound like either, though rarely and only in certain regions like /ə/.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is incorrect. IPA symbols don't relate to a "single sound" at all. One symbol may represent several different types of sound. The important thing is they all relate to one *phoneme*.

Comment: True, I deliberately glossed over subphonemes. I didn't want to muddle the point.

Comment: You seem to have written it *always relates a single sound to a single letter* - but it actually relates many sounds to a single symbol. Your answer says that the OP doesn't understand the IPA.  They seem to understand it fairly well. I think this is a post you should delete very fast, because you don't want to tell someone who understands something perhaps  better than you that they don't understand it!

Comment: When I made this answer, the post was saying that /I/ (which isn't even an IPA letter, though the question clearly stated it was) sounded like /ə/ in "sit". The question has been edited since then. I still think that the current question falls afoul of this problem, actually. The way it's written, it sounds like he's comparing three IPA letters now.

Comment: Well, I think it's very difficult to get all the symbols right all the time. I suspect that OP was using a capital 'i' that had bars on the top and bottom in their font, but when it came out in the SE font you can't see the bars so it looks like a small case 'L' . I don't think you really want to keep your answer knowing that they meant a KIT but that the SE software just gives you a straight line that looks like a small case L do you? It's OP's first question. More importantly your answer is not good for people who look this up in the future - unless you edit it. The info is completely wrong.

Comment: You could edit your answer and then I could upvote it and delete mine.

Comment: I rather like your answer. What's a concise layman definition of phoneme I can add here? Any of a group of sounds that aren't distinguished within the language at hand?